# objective-c MPMoviePlayerViewController done button language

Tags: objective-c, localization, mpmovieplayercontroller

im using a videoplayer - and realized that the "done" button seems to be labled with "done" even thogh i set "Localization native development region" to "Germany"

i tried a web video and there it was labled with "fertig"

maybe someone can help me with this.

the code snip is here:

```
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = 
[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(playbackStateChange:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayer.moviePlayer];    

[mainVc  presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer here: [Localize Done button of MPMoviePlayerViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412596/localize-done-button-of-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller)

1. check the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion in your Info.plist
2. make sure you have the German version of InfoPlist.strings
3. change the language of your Simulator to German

Comment: Just a hint for who can't find how to obtain a localized version of InfoPlist.strings: select the Project (blue icon) on the Navigator and click on the plus button at Localizations section. Then, select the language you want.

Comment: Done that. Does not help. Displays "Done". Looks like an Apple bug to me.

Since there is no view and no navigationItem yet at presentation time, there is little we can do, programmatically.

Comment: Update: The Simulator behaves differently, phone does not show the problem.