# Localize Done button of MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: ios, localization, mpmovieplayercontroller, uinavigationitem

I am using a MPMoviePlayerViewController to present videos. Everything works as expected, but if I switch the device's language to e.g. German, the "Done" button is not localized.

I tried to access the button and set it to my own button implementation like so:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

NSLog(@"%@", mp.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem); // always null, but why?

// override button with locale 
mp.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Zurück"
                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone 
                                             target:self 
                                             action:@selector(dismissMoviePlayer:)];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```

A similar question has been asked before, but never received any answers: [objective-c MPMoviePlayerViewController done button language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746051/objective-c-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-done-button-language).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sounds like a bug being that this view is provided by Apple, it should adhere to the devices language settings.

Comment: I thought so too. Guess I'll file another bugreport with Apple later. Fun times (:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` in your Info.plist

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this doesn't do the trick. I begin to think this could be another iOS bug. Any other suggestions?

Comment: No, this is not a bug. Do you have German version of InfoPlist.strings ?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.

1. check the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` in your Info.plist
2. make sure you have the German version of InfoPlist.strings
3. change the language of your Simulator to German

Comment: @changx What if my language translation (Lithuanian) isn't by default in Apple bundle? How can I manually translate that Done button? Your solution only works for those which are already translated (Works with english, german, russian etc)

Comment: would be better if I can change that Done button text programatically, because somewhere I need it to be other than this value

Comment: And what key should I put on the new localizable.strings?

Comment: Note that this will work, but only on a device. The simulator only has the `English.lproj` localization.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Info.plist in xml (Open as source code) and put your translation. For example:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>es</string>
```

To put it in spanish (Spanish doesn't appear in the list)