# Localize Done button of MPMoviePlayerViewController for unsupported Language

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization

Possible duplicate in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412596/localize-done-button-of-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller), but I asked in comments and didn't get any response, so will write here

So the main problem is to localize or change button label text programmatically for button "Done" in MPMoviePlayerViewController. In the post I linked, there is solution for those languages which by default is currently included in iPhone languages support (english, german, russian, etc), but I need to localize to Lithuanian (lt), Latvian languages (lv), which are not there. Is there any other opportunity to change that label?

Comment: did you found solution? I am looking for it...

Answer (score 0):

```
id mpBarAppearance = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class], nil];
if (!iOS > 5) [mpBarAppearance setTitle:@"YourText"];
```