# iOS: MPMoviePlayerController text doesn't match language

Tags: ios, localization, mpmovieplayercontroller

My issue is that MPMoviePlayerController is showing English text when I switch the device language to Arabic. I do have Localization enabled for both English and Arabic, and Localizable.strings for each.

The Done button, Loading... text and the options are all still in English, but apparently these have been localized for different languages. I can't seem to figure out how to get the English text to switch to Arabic (or if it is actually supported).

A similar question has been asked before here, but this was for setting the default language of the movie player by changing the Development Region: [Localize Done button of MPMoviePlayerViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8412596/localize-done-button-of-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
DemonGyro

**Edit:** This may just be an issue with the simulator as the language switches fine on the iPad. Just need to get my hands on a iPhone to check that too...

**Edit 2:** Turns out it's just an issue with the simulator. Oh well, at least my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's just an issue with the simulator. Oh well, at least my problem is solved.

Comment: What you are asking is completely unrelated to the issue I was having. My problem was that he MoviePlayerVC was not localizing the text. I suggest creating a question of your own and putting in a bit more information.

Comment: I am not asking about your issue I am asking is it possible to play audio according to localization for HLS streaming.

Comment: Yes, and I'm telling you that the best way to get any answer is to not highjack a 2 year old post with an unrelated question. Create your own question if you would like to even get any possibility of another person aside from me reading this.